# Tikz figure with multi columns table

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to read from a file with 100000 rows (I plot only the first 600) and 12 columns of data and to plot it with different colors. The data does not contain `x` components, that is why I use `x expr=\coordindex` in my code.

At the moment I am facing two problems with my plot.

1. The different columns have the same color (black)
2. The label in the legend should be `$d_1$,...,$d_{12}$` instead of `$d_0$,...,$d_{11}$`

I tried the following code:

```
\documentclass[pdftex]{scrbook}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\newcommand{\plotfile}[1]{
 \pgfplotstableread{#1}{\table}
 \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{#1}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofcols{\pgfplotsretval - 1}
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\numberofcols}{
 \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{##1}\of{\table}\to{\colname}
   \addplot[only marks, mark size=0.3pt,mark=*] table [x expr=\coordindex,y index=##1] {#1};
   \addlegendentryexpanded{$d_{##1}$}
 }
}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel={Influx},
    ylabel={Center of mass},
    grid=major,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=1,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=600,      
    legend style={
      font=\footnotesize,
      at={(1.3,1)},
      anchor=north east}]
    \plotfile{./tables/schwerpunkt_12_.0220.log}
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result I get is:

[image: plot]

**EDIT**

I was able using the tip from @Jake (color list) to create my plot with 12 different colors. What is still not solved, is that i would like to add `+1` to the number near `d`. This mean, instead of `$d_0$`, there should be `$d_1$` and etc.

My guess is that i need to create somehow a macro that do a summation of `##1 + 1` and the result of it to place in `addlegendentryexpanded{$d_{##1}$}` instead of `##1`

How could i do it?

Comment: Can you please add in a little more explanation? It's not quite clear what you're attempting to do with this code.

Comment: You need to use `\addplot+[only marks,...`. If you don't use the `+`, the colour list is deactivated. Note, however, that the default colour list only contains four different colours, so you should try one of the other `cycle list name`s (like `cycle list name=color list` or `exotic`). However, even then I doubt you'll be able to clearly tell the 12 series apart (12 is a lot).

Comment: @jake, until now i was able to get only up to four colors, and then tikz start to use different shapes... what i don't want

Comment: Do you want line plots (then you have to set `no markers`), or do you want symbols (then you have to set `only marks`)? Have you tried other cycle lists, as I described in my previous comment?

Comment: i thought that by writitng `only marks` it will not connect the points with a line, but i didnt took into consideration the symbols... need to try

Comment: @jake, i tried your suggestion, `no marker` and as you expected, it didn't do what i wanted. It used 4 colors and play with the line style by the other combinations... What about the other part of my problem, `+1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proposal. I included a small lua script to generate a data set (if you don't want to use `lualatex`, then remove the `\directlua` part and change the table file to the one containing the actual data.

To compute the sum, I use `\numexpr` (cheaper than another call to the `pgfmath` parser).

```
% Compile with lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\directlua{%
  local f1 = function (t, tau)
    return tostring(math.exp(-t/(600*tau)))
  end
  local f2 = function (t, tau, f)
    return tostring(math.exp(-t/(600*tau))*math.cos(t*f))
  end
  local filehandle, errormessage = io.open("table_example.log","w")
  for i = 1, 600 do
      filehandle:write(
        f1(i, .05) .. ";" .. 
        f1(i, .1) .. ";" .. 
        f1(i, .2) .. ";" .. 
        f1(i, .3) .. ";" .. 
        f1(i, .4) .. ";" .. 
        f1(i, .5) .. ";" .. 
        f2(i, .05, 100) .. ";" .. 
        f2(i, .1, 100) .. ";" .. 
        f2(i, .2, 100) .. ";" .. 
        f2(i, .3, 100) .. ";" .. 
        f2(i, .4, 100) .. ";" .. 
        f2(i, .5, 100) .. "\noexpand\n")
  end
  filehandle:close()}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{%
  compat = 1.5,
  cycle list name = exotic,
  table/col sep = semicolon}

\newcommand{\plotfile}[1]{%
  \pgfplotstableread{#1}{\table}
  \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{#1}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberofcols{\pgfplotsretval - 1}
  \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\numberofcols}{%
    \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{##1}\of{\table}\to{\colname}
    \addplot+[only marks, mark size=0.3pt] table [x expr=\coordindex,y
    index=##1] {#1}; 
    \addlegendentryexpanded{$d_{\number\numexpr##1+1\relax}$}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel={Influx},
    ylabel={Center of mass},
    grid=major,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=1,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=600,      
    legend style={
      font=\footnotesize,
      at={(1.3,1)},
      anchor=north east}]
    \plotfile{./table_example.log}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]